# How can I combine two object of this odd form?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I never thought about it but when using combinereducers, the syntax is odd:

```
const File = {
  Apex1,
  PeopleInput
};

const reducers = combineReducers(File);
```

Basically instead of inserting key, values into the {} you can just pass the single value of a function.

I tried doing this with strings and got an error.  I.E. this syntax is not valid.

```
const Strings = {
  'foo',
  'boo'
}
```

I have two objects of the form in File that I need to combine.  How can I go about doing this:

Can I use this method:

```
const combined = {
  ...File1,
  ...File2
};
```

This works with normal objects but I'm not sure about the form I mentioned above.

I'm trying to find some reference material on how objects behave without values and am not even sure it is supported:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects

However, this method is used in the redux docs:

https://redux.js.org/api/combinereducers

Comment: The syntax is a shorthand. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types#enhanced_object_literals, https://alligator.io/js/object-property-shorthand-es6/

Comment: everything is on the web, you just need to know how to find it, I did google but did not find it, using the spread operator does indeed work for combining two objects of this "shorthand" type ... seems "legal" to do and not an anti-pattern as well.